# GAN with not a random input

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm very interested in GAN those times.

I coded one for MNIST with the following structure :
Generator model
Discriminator model
Gen + Dis model

Generator model generate batches of image from random distribution.
Discrimator is trained over it and real images.
Then Discriminator is freeze in Gen+Dis model and Generator trained. (With the frozen Discriminator who says if the generator is good or not)

Now, imagine I don't want to feed my generator with a random distribution but with images. (For upscaling for example, or generate an real image from a draw)

Do I need to change something in it ?
(Except the conv model who will be more complex)
Should I continue to use the binary_crossentropy as loss function ?

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed put a variational autoencoder (VAE) in front in order to generate the initial distribution z (see [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.09300)).

If you are interested in the topic I can recommend the this [course](https://www.kadenze.com/courses/creative-applications-of-deep-learning-with-tensorflow/info) at Kadenze.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
For the VAE + GAN, that's exactly what I want ! Thanks!
So, if i understood well, instead of a simple decoder of noise in the generator, I put in it an autoencoder.
But, can I keep the binary_crossentropy as the loss function ?
I guess it will be slower to converge, but I don't really understand the loss function used in the paper.. (Eq.8)